# Why does the background peek through in between the outer div border and the inner div?

Tags: html, css

It's not as obvious in codepen but in my react app it's quite distracting.

```
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    
  </div>
</div>

.outside{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:20px solid skyblue ;
  border-radius:8px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.inside{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:skyblue;
}
```

[image: picture]
[codepen](https://codepen.io/chriskevini/pen/bGMgGLQ)

Comment: The problem is your border. Juste remove `border:20px solid skyblue;` 

Relative units in `%` do not take border into considaration when computing their real value.

Answer (score 0):

The pehnomenon is very obvious (at least on my Chrome/Edge on Windows10) if you just run the code you have given and zoom in and out - the lines come and go.

It's caused by screen pixels getting 'left behind' when the system has to decide how to map part pixels - 1 CSS pixel on a modern screen maps to several screen pixels.

A slight hack but it does the job is to put the background of inner onto a pseudo before element rather than on the inner element itself, making the pseudo element just slightly bigger and positioned slightly offset so it covers up those spurious lines.

```css
.outside {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 20px solid skyblue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inside {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inside::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  background-color: skyblue;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion gave me an idea. I tried it out and it worked perfectly.
We can solve the original problem by simply adding this one line of css to the inside element.
`transform:scale(1.01);`